# Cartoon with a tiger woman and a snake/serpent woman fighting in a cave

Tags: story-identification, anime, cartoon, powers

I remember only one particular scene, probably in the 2000s. But I remember a tiger woman and a snake/serpent woman fighting in a cave and the main characters had to collect some kind of stone or gem and the bad guy was controlling the snake woman, and she betrayed the main characters... in a cave. Please help me find it... it’s bugging me off, I need closure?! ><

Comment: Welcome to the site! Could you take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) and see if you can remember anything you to [edit] into the question? Every little bit helps.

Answer (score 7):

You're probably thinking of Legend of the Dragon! It was a big favorite of mine when I was a kid, and I spent a good part of my afternoon tracking it down. Are any of these characters familiar? The two woman sound like Beingal and Cobra, though I don't remember what the villain's name is. They also used stones with emblems of animals (the Chinese zodiac I think?) to power themselves up.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Are you thinking of [Cheetara](http://thundercats-ho.wikia.com/wiki/Cheetara) from [ThunderCats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ThunderCats)?

[image]

A cave would certainly fit in the setting.

[image]

And you could probably misremember [Mumm-Ra](http://thundercats-ho.wikia.com/wiki/Mumm-Ra) as a snake-woman:
[image]